# Не работают табы bootstrap - почему?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, tab

Здравствуйте! Хочу настроить переключение табов в бутстрап, но вкладки не переключают текст - почему? Код ниже:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs smile-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#homesmile" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#secondsmile" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#thirdsmile" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fourthsmile" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 4</a></li>
  </ul>                 
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="homesmile">
      Текст 1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="secondsmile">
      Текст 2
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="thirdsmile">
      Текст 3
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="fourthsmile">
      Текст 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: возможно, как-то неправильно подключаете бутстрап, так как по разметке всё правильно и работает - http://fiddle.jshell.net/140r8410/

Comment: Спасибо! из-за кофликта скриптов не работало

Answer (score 1):

99%, что Вы bootstrap.js не подключили

Comment: 1% что это скрипты конфликтовали)